# How to make a single connected app created in my dev org to autorize every salesforce user irrespective of the org to my node js application

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I've a Node Application where it's functionality is to authorize users using their salesforce credentials and show 360 view of the account information

For this I've created a connected app in salesforce and used in my node application to authorize users but the problem is my application only authorizing the users of my org but i want to authorize any user who enters valid salesforce credential

How to setup connected app for this kind of scenario's ?

[image: connected app image]

What are these configuarations in connected app like Configure ID Token,ID Token Audiences

can anybody explain in layman terms ?